# How to get a xaml window in WPF designer by using Add-ins in Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, xaml, add-in

I am a new to Add-ins in VS, I tried to use Add-ins to get a xaml window in WPF designer by using the ActiveWindow->object, however, it returns null. I can have a address if I try to get a WinForm type window the same way.

If this is not work, is it possible to catch a xaml window in WPF designer in Visual Studio ? We want to check every control in xaml window.

Thanks any help!!

Comment: Are you developing an add-in?

Comment: Yes, I want to create an  Add-in which can analyze the xaml window in VS.

Comment: I need to iterate every control in the xaml window, thanks!!

Comment: Do you want to analyze the XAML code, or the rendered view by the XAML Designer?

Comment: I want to analyze the rendered view by the XAML Designer, thanks.